# Leaflet + Backbone.js: how to update the view on model collection update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, leaflet

I have a problem with the integration between Leaflet and Backbone.js. I took a sample I found online (http://jsfiddle.net/dPqQy/) that has the following View and Model for the Map:

```
App.Views.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
id:"map",
render: function() {
    //render map element
    var map = this.map =  L.map(this.$el.attr('id'))
    .setView([this.model.get('centerLon'),  this.model.get('centerLat') ], 13)
    .addLayer(L.tileLayer(this.model.get('layerUrl'), { maxZoom: 18 }));

    //render each marker
    this.markerViews = this.model.get('markers').map(function(marker) {
        return new App.Views.MarkerView({model:marker, map:map}).render();
    });
    }
});

var map = new App.Models.Map({
    centerLon: 51.505,
    centerLat: -0.09,
    layerUrl:      'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    markers: new App.Collections.Markers([
        {id:1, latitude:-0.09, longitude:51.505},
        {id:2, latitude:-0.092, longitude:51.503},
        {id:3, latitude:-0.086, longitude:51.506}
    ])
 });

var mapView = new App.Views.MapView({model:map});
mapView.render();
```

Now, the problem is that when I try to update the marker's collection in the model with:

```
map.get('markers').add(node);
```

(node is a custom marker that I want to add, the View doesn't get updated and the marker doesn't show in the map. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

probably you should put this in your view

```
initialize: function () {
   this.listenTo(this.model, 'add', this.render);
},
```

this will update your view and map as well

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Apparently I fixed the update issue by adding this:

```
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'add', this.addMarker);
    }
```

Where the function is:

```
    addMarker: function() {

        var markers = this.model.get('markers');
        var markersLength = this.model.get('markers').length;
        var markerView = new App.Views.MarkerView({model: markers.models[markersLength-1], map:this.map});
        this.el.appendChild(markerView.render().el);
    }
```

I also had to trigger the event 'add' on the model after I add the data:

```
    map.get('markers').add(node);
    map.trigger('add');
```

Now, the problem is that the map doesn't refresh in real-time with the markers. Has anyone been successful in doing that with leaflet?